# Gantt Chart for GitHub

Tags: github, gantt-chart

We've been using GitHub for 6-months now and have more/less figured out "best practices" with regards on how to put in tasks, milestones, etc. However, from a management point of view, there are a few features that are lacking. For instance, Gantt Chart capabilities found in solutions such as RedMine, or even overlaying on top of a calendar tasks/milestone markers, roadmaps, etc.

Is there some sort of "add on" or 3rd party website that can hook into GitHub and generate these for me? Since we've already integrated so much within GitHub, I'd like to stay on it, but if a migration to another system is possible with the functionality we require, I may be willing to transfer.

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try binding with JIRA. There are many management tool that you needs.

Comment: "Closed as off-topic" drives me nuts - so frustrating. Google "Github Gantt" in attempt to find a gantt chart add on for github. The first 4 results are off topic for that search, and the 5th comes here, which should have many good answers but it is closed. Please delete this and let google take us to a better answer somewhere else. Or leave open with an "opinionated" tag, or auto move it to a sister SO sight where the question is legit. I want opinionated answers and on topic spam. Deal with real spam another way, for example: take away points for off topic comments/answers.

Comment: Found this one https://gitlab.com/ganttlab/ganttlab-live //  https://live.ganttlab.org/ works for gitlab and github (supports tokens)

Answer (score 10):

I started a project which does exactly that :

https://github.com/neyric/gh-issues-gantt

It only handles issue durations in days, but we found it to be easier to maintain and quite accurate for our usage.

Comment: And it only works for password auth https://github.com/neyric/gh-issues-gantt/issues/6#issuecomment-41027097 tokens and/or 2FA is not supported.